# fullPage.js afterSlideLoad causes plugin to be destroyed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

i'm using [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) - I am not sure if it's being destroyed or just causing some jQuery error that basically destroys all the functionality.

I'm trying to dynamically add navigation arrows for navigating between slides based on value of the var `numberSlides`. So, on load of any slide I want to check the slide (e.g `#portfolio-slide-1`) against the var `numberSlides`.

If `numberSlides = 2` and I am on slide `1`, then the righthand arrow should be shown.

If I'm on slide `2` and `numberSlides = 2` then I've already reached the end of the slides so no righthand arrow is needed.

In order to do this, I'm trying to hook my function to the callback `afterSlideLoad()`, **[link to documentation here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex)**

This is my current code:

```
$.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
if(numberSlides > 1){
   console.log("here1"); // this logs correctly
   checkCreateArrows(numberSlides);
}

function checkCreateArrows(numberSlides){
    console.log("here2"); // logs correctly

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        afterSlideLoad: function(slideIndex){

            // this is where is all goes wrong

            if(slideIndex == 1){
                console.log("First slide loaded"); // never logs
                if(slideIndex < numberSlides){
                    console.log('There is stll another slide'); // never logs
                    // so create the arrow
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So from above you can see that `checkCreateArrows()` is working because the `here2` logs.

However as soon as it hits the `.fullpage` function the whole thing falls over. No errors, but the fullpage functions to define the heights of all the sections collapse, all the CSS added by fullpage no longer works. I have no idea what's happening. And the slide won't navigate correctly.

So what am I doing wrong?

I expect I've used `afterSlideLoad` incorrectly and it's causing jQuery after it to break?

I have no idea how to debug this. Does my code look wrong?

Comment: Reproduce it online in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/418/).

Answer (score 0):

`afterSlideLoad` has 4 parameters [according to the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex), and you should use them same order:

```
afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){

}
```